# Available Keyboard Shortcuts for Web Applications

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I'm working on a web application and I'd like to add some keyboard shortcuts.  Things like Ctrl-N, or Ctrl-Space. However, I **do not** want to use a keyboard shortcut that's already used by the browser.

For example, using the Ctrl-Space shortcut in Google Chrome on OS X is fine, but in Firefox on OS X it brings up a right-click menu in the browser.

Is there a known list of cross browser/OS keyboard shortcuts that are safe (or unsafe) to use for web applications?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you need to know only standard browser keyboard shortcuts, they are listed [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/02/standard-browser-keyboard-shortcuts.html).

Separate browser's shortcuts lists:

- Internet Explorer's shortcuts can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15357/windows-internet-explorer-11-keyboard-shortcuts).
- Firefox's [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Keyboard%20shortcuts). (scroll down a bit)
- Google Chrome's [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179).
- Safari's [official source here](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/keyboard-and-other-shortcuts-cpsh003/mac), but a better one is [here](https://shortcutworld.com/Safari/mac/Safari-Browser_Shortcuts).
- Opera's [here](https://help.opera.com/en/latest/shortcuts/).

And I find [this](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/firefox/keyboard.htm) comparison table ugly, but very useful.

Comment: This is (at least any longer) not a complete list, especially if you include things like Chromebooks

Comment: Wow, that comparison table is missing at least 9 (of the most useless) shortcuts in Chrome, specifically Ctrl+# where # is in 1..9

Answer (score 13):

- There are no open shortcuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Option</kbd> may be less familiar to users, but they are largely open.
- If there is no input focus, you should use plain keys, e.g. <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, etc.
- There are **five** open keyboard shortcuts using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

```js
// (Ctrl ≅ ⌘ on OSX)
Ctrl + Shift + L
Ctrl + Shift + O
Ctrl + Shift + S
Ctrl + Shift + U
Ctrl + Shift + Y
```

This list was derived from Chrome's keyboard shortcut list, F. David McRitchie's [Comparison Table](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/firefox/keyboard.htm), and contributions from @leonbloy, @KnowYourElements, @Dietmar, and @jellyberg in the comments.

Please comment if any of these are not available on Windows or other browsers, and I will edit the list accordingly. The list was longer a couple years ago, but browsers do add new keyboard shortcuts from time to time.

Comment: Please refrain from using plain keys, it breaks expectations that only modifier keys + enter are used to execute state changes.

Comment: @Fletcher91 I'm not aware of such expectations. Plain key state changes are common. For example, in Gmail '#' deletes, 'e' archives, 's' stars, etc.

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + E` `Ctrl + Shift + K` used in Firefox

Comment: `Ctrl + B` is used in Firefox as bookmark.

Comment: about using plain keys, it sometimes/often happens to me (so I assume it also happens to others) that I start typing and am not inside a form field. This has more than once made unwanted changes in JIRA for example, where plain keys are also used for shortcuts. I agree that this is more my fault than the program's, but it does happen and would be good to take into account if people can type things on your page

Comment: so uh... am I reading correctly that there are only *seven* Ctrl based shortcuts that are safe to use?

Comment: Ctrl+U is used in Firefox and Chrome to display the page source code.
Ctrl+I is used in Firefox to display page info (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly)

Comment: In Chrome Mac, Cmd+Shift+F is Always show toolbar in full screen