# Javascript how to listen keyboard shortcut?

Tags: javascript, listener, keyboard-shortcuts, keypress

I try to use javascript listen the shortcut of keyboard, such as "command+shift+4"
My current solution is : [on Mac]

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.shiftKey && e.metaKey && e.keyCode == 52) {
        alert("Here it is.");
    }
}, false);
```

But since the shortcut "command+shift+4" is the default "screenshot" of Mac, so the javascript can not capture it. If I change the 52 to 53, then this code works, but it listens to "command+shift+5".

Is there some solution let javascript listen to the default shortcut of Mac?

Comment: The priority is the operating system. If that allows to bubble the event - you can listen on. Otherwise, sorry :( Can you imagine ALT+F4 being stopped by Javascript? that would be at the least extremely annoying.

Comment: It is up to the host which events it dispatches into a document. If the document doesn't get an event, it can't respond.

Answer (score 4):

Your browser is running underneath your operating system. If you "catch" the keypress event on the OS level and don't let it pass through ( imagine `e.stopPropagation()` ), you are unable to catch it in your browser. It's the same thing as if you were trying to bind something to `Alt+F4` - this event is handled before it gets to the browser's on-page events. Some may pass through and some might not.

If you are able to, change the shortcut to a OS/browser independent one.
Avoid [these keyboard shortcuts](http://www.adiwebs.com/47-browser-independent-shortcuts/). Also you might want to [read this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941180/available-keyboard-shortcuts-for-web-applications)

To make sure your shortcut is recognized correctly simply do an output of your keypress

```
window.onkeyup = function(e){
    var pressed = "";
    if(e.shiftKey){
        pressed += " + Shift";
    }else if(e.ctrlKey){
        pressed += " + Ctrl";
    } //and so on
    pressed += e.keyCode;
    console.log(pressed);
}
```